# Live preview with Vim-LaTeX not updating live

Tags: vim, vim-latex, live-preview

I have been using [Vim-LaTeX](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) for quite some time now. However, each time I want to see a change, I have to save the document, compile it with `\ll`, and then preview it with `\lv`.

Today, I decided to install [Vim Latex Live Preview](https://github.com/xuhdev/vim-latex-live-preview) plugin. I installed it manually by copying `plugin/latexlivepreview.vim` to `~/.vim/plugin`.

I can launch the preview by typing `:LLPStartPreview` as intended. However, it does **not** update live (as I type). To see the change, I have to save the document (`:w`) first in order to trigger the compilation. What is the problem here? Is there some clashing happening with the compilation system of Vim-LaTeX suite? How do I fix it?

P.S. I have asked this question and Vi and Vim Stack Exchange, but it was not answered. Hopefully, this question isn't unsuitable for this community.

Comment: What does `vim --version` show for python and python3/dyn?

Comment: Thank you for getting involved. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

False alarm... I have just realized that it actually works as intended. It just takes 9 seconds on average for a single word to be updated.

I did not notice that before as I did not wait that long to see a change before saving or exiting.

The slow time may be caused because my computer is pretty old. I am running on hardware from 2006.

Comment: That doesn't sound unreasonable with a default `updatetime` of 4s and then a few seconds for `pdflatex` to run